# Popup list of selectInput is hiding behind navBarPage

Tags: shiny

Please consider below ShinyApp with navBarPage & selectInput.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                  "Transmission" = "am",
                  "Gears" = "gear")),
    navbarPage(title = "",
                tabPanel("Scene 01",
                                    fluidRow(tableOutput("data"))
                ),
                tabPanel("Scene 02", fluidRow()))
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$data <- renderTable({
      mtcars[, c("mpg", input$variable), drop = FALSE]
    }, rownames = TRUE)
  }
)
```

As you see, when the popup-baloon of selectInput opens (i.e. when User clicks on the drop-down icon of selectInput), it hides behind the strip of navBarPage. Is there any way to bring that popup-baloon forward, instead of hiding behind the navBarPage srip.

Appreciate for your help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use css to make the `z-index` of selectinput dropdown more than that of nav-bar header using the following tag:

`tags$div(tags$style(HTML( ".selectize-dropdown, .selectize-dropdown.form-control{z-index:10000;}")))`

In your app it would be as follows:

```
shinyApp(
      ui = fluidPage(
        tags$div(tags$style(HTML( ".selectize-dropdown, .selectize-dropdown.form-control{z-index:10000;}"))),
        selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                    c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                      "Transmission" = "am",
                      "Gears" = "gear")),
        navbarPage(title = "",
                   tabPanel("Scene 01",
                            fluidRow(tableOutput("data"))
                   ),
                   tabPanel("Scene 02", fluidRow()))
      ),
      server = function(input, output) {
        output$data <- renderTable({
          mtcars[, c("mpg", input$variable), drop = FALSE]
        }, rownames = TRUE)
      }
    )
```

You will get something like this:

[image]

Hope it helps!